# Union All in Sub query while updating a table in Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a below query in `Big Query`. I am trying to `update` a table using this query. I invoke the sql command from CLI.

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "UPDATE data_set.table_to_update A 
                                SET D_A_AMOUNT = B.D_A_AMOUNT, A_FEE = B.A_FEE, 
                                O_T_AMOUNT = B.O_T_AMOUNT, U_FEE = B.U_FEE, 
                                UPDATED_DATETIME = B.UPDATED_DATETIME, UPDATED_BY = B.UPDATED_BY 
                                    FROM data_set.table_to_update C 
                                    INNER JOIN ( 
                                    SELECT CAST(131.27 AS NUMERIC) AS D_A_AMOUNT, CAST(20.66 AS NUMERIC) AS A_FEE, 
                                    '12345' AS TRANSACTION_KEY, CAST(145871.0 AS NUMERIC) AS O_T_AMOUNT, 
                                    CAST(131.27 AS NUMERIC) AS U_FEE, '2022-09-28 15:30:47' AS UPDATED_DATETIME, 
                                    'APPLE_USER' AS UPDATED_BY, 'P_S_US' AS L_IDENTITY ) B 
                                    ON C.TRANSACTION_KEY = B.TRANSACTION_KEY  WHERE C.L_IDENTITY = 'P_S_US';"
```

This query runs absolutely fine.

Now I am trying to add a `UNION ALL` statement like below.

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "UPDATE data_set.table_to_update A 
                                SET D_A_AMOUNT = B.D_A_AMOUNT, A_FEE = B.A_FEE, 
                                O_T_AMOUNT = B.O_T_AMOUNT, U_FEE = B.U_FEE, 
                                UPDATED_DATETIME = B.UPDATED_DATETIME, UPDATED_BY = B.UPDATED_BY 
                                    FROM data_set.table_to_update C 
                                    INNER JOIN ( 
                                    SELECT CAST(131.27 AS NUMERIC) AS D_A_AMOUNT, CAST(20.66 AS NUMERIC) AS A_FEE, 
                                    '12345' AS TRANSACTION_KEY, CAST(145871.0 AS NUMERIC) AS O_T_AMOUNT, 
                                    CAST(131.27 AS NUMERIC) AS U_FEE, '2022-09-28 15:30:47' AS UPDATED_DATETIME, 
                                    'APPLE_USER' AS UPDATED_BY, 'P_S_US' AS L_IDENTITY 
                                    UNION ALL  
                                    SELECT CAST(134.19 AS NUMERIC) AS D_A_AMOUNT, CAST(21.31 AS NUMERIC) AS A_FEE, 
                                    '987654232' AS TRANSACTION_KEY, CAST(149112.0 AS NUMERIC) AS O_T_AMOUNT, 
                                    CAST(134.19 AS NUMERIC) AS U_FEE, '2022-09-28 15:30:47' AS UPDATED_DATETIME, 
                                    'APPLE_USER' AS UPDATED_BY, 'P_S_US' AS L_IDENTITY) B 
                                    ON C.TRANSACTION_KEY = B.TRANSACTION_KEY  WHERE C.L_IDENTITY = 'P_S_US';"
```

I am getting below error

```
UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row
```

I am a newbie to `Big Query`. I am unable to figure out what the issue is here.

How can I make my second query to work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is create a temp table using the UNION ALL statement and then join like below

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE data_set.update_union AS (
                            SELECT CAST(131.27 AS NUMERIC) AS D_A_AMOUNT, CAST(20.66 AS NUMERIC) AS A_FEE, 
                            '12345' AS TRANSACTION_KEY, CAST(145871.0 AS NUMERIC) AS O_T_AMOUNT, 
                            CAST(131.27 AS NUMERIC) AS U_FEE, '2022-09-28 15:30:47' AS UPDATED_DATETIME, 
                            'APPLE_USER' AS UPDATED_BY, 'P_S_US' AS L_IDENTITY 
                            UNION ALL  
                            SELECT CAST(134.19 AS NUMERIC) AS D_A_AMOUNT, CAST(21.31 AS NUMERIC) AS A_FEE, 
                            '987654232' AS TRANSACTION_KEY, CAST(149112.0 AS NUMERIC) AS O_T_AMOUNT, 
                            CAST(134.19 AS NUMERIC) AS U_FEE, '2022-09-28 15:30:47' AS UPDATED_DATETIME, 
                            'APPLE_USER' AS UPDATED_BY, 'P_S_US' AS L_IDENTITY); 
                            UPDATE data_set.table_to_update A 
                            SET D_A_AMOUNT = B.D_A_AMOUNT, A_FEE = B.A_FEE, 
                            O_T_AMOUNT = B.O_T_AMOUNT, U_FEE = B.U_FEE, 
                            UPDATED_DATETIME = B.UPDATED_DATETIME, UPDATED_BY = B.UPDATED_BY 
                            FROM data_set.table_to_update C 
                            INNER JOIN data_set.update_union B 
                            ON C.TRANSACTION_KEY = B.TRANSACTION_KEY  
                            WHERE C.L_IDENTITY = 'P_S_US' AND 1 > 0 and C.TRANSACTION_KEY = A.TRANSACTION_KEY;"
```